# How to Dynamically populate values in a UIPicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipickerview

Ok, maybe I'm missing something really simple and I apologize if that's the case, however, I've googled every permutation of the title and have not found! 
Here's my question, my requirement is when i select a country name in a uipicker component, the cities of that country should be loaded in the second UIPicker component. 
So what i want to do ryt now is, i have 2 picker views side by side and when the user selects a row in country picker i want to re-initiate the second picker with appropriate data.

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: I have a question that from where you get cities of country whether it is form web service or static or from database

Comment: @DhavalVaishnani: ryt now i am using NSMutableArray for both the pickers. one contains the country names and the other holding the city   names.
Does it really matter from where i am getting the cities or countries?
i mean even if am getting the values for cities and countries from a web service call den whats the big deal? can u pls let me knw

Comment: I want to know it because I can code it as your desire way so

Comment: ok thanks 4 ur time n interest in d question. eagerly waiting for ur next reply with the code ..

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
 [pickerView reloadAllComponents]
```

To reload the components, and place the right one with:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  return [titles objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [UIPickerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDelegate), there is *pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:* which is called when user select value.